# Swift - Using value from UISlider IBAction in another function

Tags: swift, uislider, identifier, xcode6.4

This is a super basic question that is troubling me.

I have a UIslider IBAction that is generating a Double (var = rounded). I want to use this double in viewDidLoad. but getting the error "**Use of unresolved identifier 'rounded'**"

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var currentValue = Double(sender.value)
    var rounded = Double(round(100*currentValue)/100)
    label.text = "\(rounded)"
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("puppy", withExtension: "jpg")
    let beginImage = CIImage(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
    filter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter.setValue(rounded, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
    let newImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage)
    self.imageView.image = newImage
}
```

**filter.setValue(rounded, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)** is where i am getting the error. I want to use the 'rounded' variable from the slider function here.

Any help in using one variable from one function in another function would be very much appreciated. I have ran into this a couple times without success. So once you all help me out here, it should fix my other issues as well.

Thanks

Comment: I think you lacking basic concepts: i) rounded variable is not class variable so can be accessed only in the function where it is defined. ii) Even it was a class variable, there would be no use of accessing that variable at viewDidLoad because this function is called before the value of rounded is set.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Lacking basic concepts, indeed. but still learning. so i'll get it eventually :-) - how would you fix my code to achieve the result i am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare an instance variable at the beginning of the class – outside any method – with the default value of the `UISlider`

   ```
   var rounded : Double = <defaultValueOfTheSlider>
   ```
2. delete the keyword `var` before `rounded` in `sliderValueChanged()`

Comment: thank you for your help! we're getting closer, but rounded still has no effect on filter.setValue(rounded, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey) inside of viewdidload.

Comment: as Shoaib mentioned `viewDidLoad()` is called very early – in any case before `sliderValueChanged()`, so you have to change the filter setting also in the `sliderValueChanged()` method

Comment: In theory, I now know why it isn't working as I intended (thanks to all you folks helping me out!) I created a function of all the code inside viewDidLoad, and i am calling it in sliderValueChanged. It works, however it's extremely inefficient because it's setting fileURL / beginImage / newImage everytime the slider moves. I just don't know how to adjust the code so it only effects the filter settings. Any code snippets would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A few concepts that will help you out.
The issue you are having is that you are creating an instance inside a function and it is lost when the function returns. The reason for this is that the functions data is created on the stack, the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) is temporary memory your app's process uses.

To access the variable throughout the class you can declare it at the top of your class. This will then be allocated to the [heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) so that it's available for later access until removed from the heap(deallocated).